# invalid argument for .css()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, browser

I'm using this code with jquery

```
$(".tab").css({'background-color': '#f3f6ed', 'border': '4px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1)', 'border-bottom': 'none'});
```

It's to change the style for a tab when I click on it. It works in browsers expect for explorer (stupid microsoft..) I get "invalid argument"

Not sure how I can fix this.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to quote your object keys (unless they contain a dash, of course...) since this isn't JSON. `{border: `4px solid...`} is sufficient.

Comment: @Matt - I think you mean object literal. JSON is a subset meant for data exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't test right now, but my suspicion is the `rgba` part in

```
rgba(0,0,0,0.1)
```

IE [doesn't support rgba colour values](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/) until version 9.

I'm not sure whether there is a jQuery workaround for this. [`jQuery.support()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) doesn't seem to be able to sniff `rgba` support.

In the worst case, you'll have to test for browsers that support the property.

**Update:** The [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) library can test for `rgba` support.

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure because `rgba` isn't supported in IE; a reason why it throws the error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what kind of error you are getting, but if it is a javascript error, I would simply put the properties in a class and use jquery's `.addClass()` instead.

I would probably do that anyway...

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Whenever you encounter a hyphenated property, like `background-color`, you have to switch to the camel-case version, i.e. `backgroundColor`.</strike> Edit: As pointed out by Pekka, this was utter nonsense.

Comment: Oh, wow, you're absolutely right. I thought, actually, that JS itself wasn't accepting hyphens as part of property names. I must have picked that up wrongly somewhere. :(

Comment: @Thomas native JS indeed doesn't, but jQuery translates it internally. This library is going to be the death of us one day, making us fat and lazy because it does *everything* :)

Comment: @TJ: It shall serve as a cautionary tale for those that follow.

Comment: @Pekka: I was actually surprised, that it doesn't translate `rgba()` into an IE-supported version yet.